# ASP.NET Identity without RememberMe doesn't require login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity. On login form I uncheck RememberMe, so when the browser is closed and reopened then the login form should show up again.

Internally I call during login:

> Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager.SignIn(user,
>   isPersistent, rememberBrowser)

Both isPersistent and rememberBrowser properties are false.

During debugging on my local machine I've found out that time to time if the browser is closed and reopened I'm still singed in. It looks like that authentication cookie is not deleted.